# Asyncronious FragmentManager commit

Tags: android, android-volley, fragmentmanager

I know this issue was asked before, but I couldn't find any usable answer for my problem. Imagine application, which uses Google.Volley library for RESTful api. When app launches MainActivity shows dialogFragment(Loading) and when response comes, I would like to commit FragmentTransaction, and show data to the user like this.

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, parameterJson, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
    {//parse data and present them

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainScreenFragment.newInstance(gaObservers))
                .commit(); //i know that i can use commitAllowingStateLoss but app crashes on rotation change because of IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
    {
    }
});
```

so what is best practice here please? Any help will be appreciated.
PS: I have read [Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html), but I feel like I cant avoid async commit. Thank you

Comment: What error messages do you get when you use `commit()`? Do you get error messages when you use `cocmmitAllowingStateLoss()`?

Comment: whit commit() im getting "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" and when i use commitAllowingStateLoss(), app doesn't crash when phone locks, but on orientation change, because i call async request in OnCreate(), I'm getting IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed....Thank you for your time!

Comment: @VamsiChalla I reorganized my code, so I did that loading in Activity, and after loading I create Fragments and display data.

Comment: @beretis, Yeah even i changed the fragment transaction code to oncreate and now its working fine. Thanks!!!